# Why we can see images behind a concave mirror despite it forming real images in front of it?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Why we can see images behind a concave mirror despite it forming real images in front of it?

Many say it is illusion of the eye but if so, how can I even see it in mobile pictures?
And all rays from each point converge at respective point of the image then no rays went into the side, then how we are able to see images behind mirror even from side view although all rays from every point of obj converge at respective point of image **only** than how can we see the image from top or side where rays I think not reaching?

Comment: For a mobile the same is true that was said for eyes: it is a focusing  system with a lens. You simply don't need a real image if you have a focusing system, because adequate adaption (varying focal length, varying distance between sensor and lens) will provide a real image for you. That is, the system will focus the light on the retina. The one and only difference at the distance where a real image is formed is, that no additional focus is needed here.

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 Please post answers as answers, not as comments